# Database update with the new table values

Tags: android, database

How to update the values of the table in the android database? In the below code, it is inserted, but not updated, if it is updated, the all values shows 0. what is wrong with this code

```
    private void InsertINcurrentinfo(int iNCallsToLN, int iNLocalCallsM,
        int iNLocalCallsL, int iNSTDCallsHM, int iNSTDCallsM,
        int iNSTDCallsL, int iNgp1, int iNgp2, int iNgp3, int iNSplCalls) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);  
        Cursor cursor = myDB.query(TABLE_CURRENTINFO, null, null, null,null, null, null);
        int cnt=cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("value1", String.valueOf(iNCallsToLN));
        initialValues.put("value2", String.valueOf(iNLocalCallsM));
        initialValues.put("value3", String.valueOf(iNLocalCallsL));
        initialValues.put("value4", String.valueOf(iNSTDCallsHM));
        initialValues.put("value5", String.valueOf(iNSTDCallsM));
        initialValues.put("value6", String.valueOf(iNSTDCallsL));
        initialValues.put("value7", String.valueOf(iNgp1));



        if(cnt==0){
            myDB.insert(TABLE_CURRENTINFO, null, initialValues);
        }else{
            myDB.update(TABLE_CURRENTINFO, initialValues, null, null);
        }
        if (myDB != null) {
            myDB.close();
        }

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if (myDB != null) {
            myDB.close();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error occured while updating Current CallInfo"+ex.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Did u checked whether you are getting the value in the function parameters are the right value.Or it is also 0.

Comment: have you tried using it like: iNCallsToLN+"" instead of using String.valueOf(iNCallsToLN) in your code?

Comment: Your guess is right Mr. Arun.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `startManagingCursor(cursor);` before `int cnt=cursor.getCount();`